# How to extract string with regex

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, image-resizing

I'm using a this technic for resizing images on-the-fly, that uses the .htaccess and some php script.

in the .htaccess i have this:

```
# BEGIN ImageResizing
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /

 RewriteRule ^img-small/([A-Za-z0-9/_-]+).(jpg|gif|png)$ images.php?max_width=100&imgfile=$1.$2
</ifmodule>
# END ImageResizing
```

[images.php](http://sneak.co.nz/projects/img-resizing/php-resizing-v2.zip) is the script that does the actual resize

this regex expression:

```
^img-small/([A-Za-z0-9/_-]+).(jpg|gif|png)$
```

matches this path:

```
http://yoursite.com/img-large/myimagepath/myimage.jpg
```

and then sends it to the images.php script as arguments $1.$2

```
images.php?max_width=100&imgfile=$1.$2
```

My question is: How can I make this work if I have a path like this:

```
http://yoursite.com/myimagepath/min_myimage.jpg
```

I tried to to build a expression like this:

```
^([A-Za-z0-9/_-]+/)+(min_)([A-Za-z0-9]+).(jpg|gif|png)$
```

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/V-2URp3iB01ZuoLK)

I think the problem is on the second part of the RewriteRule

```
images.php?max_width=100&imgfile=$1.$2
```

I tried to change to something like:

images.php?max_width=100&imgfile=$1+$3.$4

this is the firt lines of the php script:

```
// max_width and image variables are sent by htaccess

$max_height = 1000;

$image = $_GET["imgfile"];
$max_width = $_GET["max_width"];
if (strrchr($image, '/')) {
$filename = substr(strrchr($image, '/'), 1); // remove folder references
} else {
$filename = $image;
}

$size = getimagesize($image);
$width = $size[0];
$height = $size[1];
```

Comment: Specifically, what server error are you getting?

Comment: Maybe: http://regexr.com?37ds4

Comment: @BlackVegetabl 500 internal

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?
URL to match: `http://yoursite.com/myimagepath/min_myimage.jpg`

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^.*/([A-Za-z0-9/_-]+).(jpg|gif|png)$ images.php?max_width=100&imgfile=$1.$2
```

If not, which server error are you getting?

Comment: i need to send the full path of the real, unresized image to the script, your solution will send min_myimage as $1, and that file does not exist.

Comment: Then try this. It worked for me.

`RewriteRule ^(.*)\/([A-Za-z0-9/_\-]+)\.(jpg|gif|png)$ images.php?max_width=100&imgfile=$1/$2.$3`

Answer (score 0):

I think we need to know more definitively about the combinations of paths and names you want rewrite to handle.  But here's one that works for all images conforming to a basic naming pattern ending in the file extensions you specify

## [Fiddle](http://fiddle.re/8m7cw)